# is there a way to scrape data from a google studio dashboard into a csv or excel?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, looker-studio

I have the ability to view but now export a data dashboard developed in google data studio.  I was hoping to see if anyone has a open-source code in python that I can use to scrape displayed data from a dashboard that lives in Google Data Studio?

Comment: There is an API. Maybe this will solve your problem in a better way? https://developers.google.com/datastudio

Comment: 1. Can you explain a bit more on the use case? 2. Do you have access to the underlying data? 3. Do you have edit access to the dashboard?

Comment: to the first response... I don't have administrative access to the underlying data so I can create an API.  However, I have access to read the data from a dashboard.  I was hoping there was a python code that could scrap data from a dashboard in google data studio.